# Forcing text left in a Div

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb pages showing in a div.( 25px high by 700px wide) The trouble is I have so many pages that the page titles in the breadcrumb are spilling out of the div. Is there a way for the last few breadcrumbs pages to force the first breadcrumb pages left out of sight and diplay the last ones fitted in the Div

Hope this makes sense

Regards

R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `overflow`, `float` and `white-space`.

HTML:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
    Start aaaa aaaa End
    </div>
</div>
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
    Start aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa End
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb-container {
    float:left; max-width:100%; margin:5px; overflow-x:hidden; background:orange;
}
.breadcrumb {
    float:right; margin:5px; white-space:nowrap; background:cyan;
}
```

This will force the links to stay on a single line and hide any overflowing text off the left hand side, so the last categories are visible.  The `float:left` stops the breadcrumbs from starting from the right margin.

Comment: I believe this is a big step towards the solution, and was about to give you +1, but I didn't manage to get in working in jsfiddle. Perhaps you want to have a look and see what is the missing piece? http://jsfiddle.net/zCwQD/1/

Comment: OK, I managed to sort it out.  http://jsfiddle.net/MQndr/2/ I will update the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in Chrome; heck knows what earlier versions of IE will make of it though:

#### HTML

```
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>1 breadcrumb item</li>
    <li>2 breadcrumb item</li>
    ...
    <li>10 breadcrumb item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.breadcrumb-container {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb-container .breadcrumb {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb-container .breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bu4J5/2/

Comment: Thanks works well in Firefox, but not in IE. Seems IE doesnt like the Float or White-space: nowrap. Any one know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

[This is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/nWnf9/) how I would do it

Comment: Nice approach, but not completely what the OP asked for. Remove link2 till 5 from your example and you will see that link 1 moved to the right of the breadcrumb. The OP wants link 1 to stay on the left when there is enough space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `overflow: hidden` to hide the content beyond the div size so that it will not break the design.

```
div
{
text-align:right;
width:700px;
height:25px;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

You can get more details about this at 
http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html